# Why is it wrong to prove the first fundamental theorem of calculus by geometric argument?

Tags: integration

I read from the Apostol book calculus Vol 1 that the First fundamental theorem of calculus is as follows:

Let $f$ be a function that is integrable on $[a,x]$ for each $x$ in $[a,b]$. let $c$ be such that $a\le c\le b$ and define a new function $A$ as follows:

$$A(x) = \int^x_c f(t)$$

if $a\le x\le b$. Then the derivative $A'(x)$ exists at each point $x$ in the open interval $(a,b)$ where $f$ is continuous, and for such $x$ we have

$$A'(x)=f(x)$$

The book gives a geometric argument as follows:

$$\int^{x+h}_x f(t)dt = \int^{x+h}_c f(t)dt - \int^{x}_c f(t)dt = A(x+h) - A(x)$$

Assuming $f$ is continuous in $[x,x+h]$, then by mean-value theorem for integrals, then we have $A(x+h) -A(x) = hf(z)$ where $x\le z \le x+h$.

The book told us that the above proof is flawed. What's wrong with this argument? Yes it assumes the continuity of interval $[x,x+h]$, but that's what the assumption of the theorem is about, right?

Comment: The argument assumes that integrals add as we expect areas to add, but we cannot make that assumption without a proof.

Comment: @RobArthan I disagree with your comment. Please see below.

Comment: Theorem 1.17 on additivity with respect to the interval of integration appears long before this discussion of Theorem 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Apostol points out, this argument depends on the continuity of $f$ in the *interval* $[x,x+h]$ because one of the hypotheses of the mean value theorem for integrals is continuity *on the whole interval of integration*. It is flawed in the sense that it is not sufficient if all we assume is continuity of $f$ *at $x$*. Instead, we must assume continuity in a neighborhood of $x$.

I disagree with the comment above by Rob Arthan. At this stage of the book, Apostol has already developed more than enough theory concerning integrals. Though Apostol calls the argument "geometric" and gives an illustration with areas, the proof itself doesn't rely in any way on the geometric concept of area.

Edit: I will quote more of what Apostol says in that section of the book.

> Hence we have $(A(x+h) - A(x))/h = f(z)$, and, since $x \leq z \leq x + h$, we find that $f(z) \to f(x)$ as $h \to 0$ through positive values. A similar argument is valid if $h \to 0$ through negative values. Therefore $A'(x)$ exists and is equal to $f(x)$.

> This argument assumes that the function $f$ is continuous in some *neighborhood* of the point $x$. However, the hypothesis of the theorem refers only to continuity of $f$ at a *single point* $x$. Therefore, we use a different method to prove the theorem under this weaker hypothesis.

Comment: It looks like Apostol should have made it clearer exactly what he meant.

Comment: @RobArthan I referred to the book and found the explanation very clear. I believe the OP's misunderstanding of Apostol's intention led him to omit certain parts of the explanation.

Comment: Just to give a simple example of a function that's (Riemann) integrable on $[-1,1]$ and continuous *at* $x=0$ but not continuous in any *neighborhood* of $0$ (because it's discontinous at $x=\pm1/n$ for all $n\ge1$), consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }x=0\\\\
{\displaystyle1\over\displaystyle\left\lfloor{1\over|x|}\right\rfloor}&\text{if }x\not=0\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the theorem's description. It never said $f$ is continuous in the open interval $(a,b)$. Instead, it said whenever $f$ is continuous at some location $x$ where $a\le x\le b$, then $A'(x)$ exists. That's a weaker assumption.

Comment: By the way, I am surprised that $f$ can be continuous at $x=0$ but not any neighborhood of $0$. Mini proof: we can always find an $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ and let $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$. How to prove it is integrable? It looks like a step function, but things get out of my imagination when getting closer to $0$.

Comment: @DachuanHuang It's easy to construct a function $f$ continuous at $0$ but not in any neighborhood of $0$. Pick any function $f$ such that $-|x| \leq f(x) \leq |x| $ and $f$ has discontinuities (for example jump discontinuities) at $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$, with $a_n \to 0$. Try to draw a graph like this and you'll see that there are many ways to do it.

Comment: It's interesting to re-discover that the definition of continuity is for a point and does not say anything about its neighborhood.